# Use Spark for text mining with nltk

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, nltk, text-mining

I have a problem with spark and text mining. Help me, please. I attached all of the errors for better identifying. I can't find anything for debugging this error. I don't know why Python doesn't answer when I type words.collect().
I downloaded the spark for Apache Hadoop 2.6 and unpacked. I'm trying to turn this code but throws me an error.

**This is my code:**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName('spark-NLTK')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();

import nltk

data = sc.textFile('c:/Users/Ramin/Desktop/Nixon.txt')

#word tokenization
def word_tokenize(x):
    lowerW = x.lower()
    return nltk.word_tokenize(x)

words = data.flatMap(word_tokenize)
words.collect()
```

**I get this error:**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 364, in main
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 69, in read_command
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\transitionparser.py", line 22, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 718, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _pytest._code
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\C:\\Bigdata\\SPARK\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.4.6.jar'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 364, in main
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 69, in read_command
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 173, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 587, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Bigdata\SPARK\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\transitionparser.py", line 22, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 718, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _pytest._code
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\Users\Ramin\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\C:\\Bigdata\\SPARK\\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.4.6.jar'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$15.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: It will be hard for us to know how to help you since we don't know what is in the file `c:/Users/Ramin/Desktop/Nixon.txt`. Can you share a sample of what is in that file?

Comment: https://github.com/raminbazr/Nixon/blob/master/Nixon.txt                                                           I upload it there.

Comment: I was able to run your code without issue. Here are some things that might help:
(1) Can you post what version of Spark you are using? (2) Can you share the entire stacktrace, if what you posted is some snippet from it?

Comment: Thanks, Katya. (1) I use spark 2.4.6 (2) That's it ( I got this code from   https://github.com/Big-Data-School/SparkCourse/blob/master/NLP/Nixon.py)

Comment: Are you sure there is no more output to the traceback? Usually, in python, where it says "Traceback (most recent call last):", there is a whole set of stacktraces, showing you through code where the error occurred. There is *nothing* else? If not, I probably can't help you, as I can't recreate the failure and there isn't enough info in the error message you shared to identify it.

Comment: thanks, Katya. I attached all of the errors above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some part of your Spark configuration is incorrect, as it thinks it needs to prepend the C drive twice to the path of your Spark libraries

```
C:\\C:\\Bigdata\\SPARK
```

So, I would attempt at running included Spark sample code like `SparkPi` before jumping in with code elsewhere